# Select only 1 row with spring repository and @Query annotation

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

```
    @Query("SELECT s FROM MyMessage s WHERE s.status = ?1 AND s.provider = ?2 ORDER BY s.insertDate ASC")
    MyMessage getOneByStatusAndProvider(MyMessageType status, Provider provider);
```

I need change this query and select only 1 row. 
The following options are not suitable for me:

1. use nativeQuery
2. use Pageble
3. findTop1ByStatusAndProvider

Comment: How about adding `LIMIT 1` to the query?

Comment: I'm curious why `findTop1ByStatusAndProvider` isn't suitable; why it has to be with `@Query annotation`.